# No handlers could be found for logger "rdflib.term"

Tags: rdflib

I am using rdflib-4.0.1 and rdfextras-0.4 in my python modules.

I get the following message while loading data into a rdfstore:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "rdflib.term"
```

What is it I am missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "No handlers" warning comes from Python's standard `logging` module. A logger needs a handler to determine what it should do with messages that have been logged -- should the text be sent to disk or to the console, for instance. See [Python 2 Logging HOWTO on Handlers](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers). Loggers also have names so that logging messages can be controlled in different ways for separate parts of the program. RDFLib writes to a logger named `"rdflib.term"` in its term.py.

I've used [`logging.basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to setup some reasonable defaults when using RDFLib:

```python
import logging
import rdflib

logging.basicConfig()

# now load your graph
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.load("life_the_universe_everything.rdf")
```

This time when you load your graph you should see rdflib's log messages in the console instead of the "No handlers" warning.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about rdflib is that [it logs when you import it](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/__init__.py#L94) because it does

```
if _interactive_mode:
    logger.info("RDFLib Version: %s" % __version__)
else:
    logger.debug("RDFLib Version: %s" % __version__)
```

in its `__init__.py`. So whereas many things log, rdflib has the distinction of logging very early, and in unusual contexts. This is fine if there's a handler, even if it's the default handler, but in many cases there's not, so you get this little logspam.

Lest ye be tempted to open a bug, please [read this one first](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/pull/662#issuecomment-261492680).